# Buffer overflow in c and order of pushing local variables on stack

Tags: c, buffer

Firstly, I'm using this compilation flags:
`gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m 32`

**Ok lets look, on code below**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char pass[8];
    char logged = 'n';
    strcpy( pass, argv[1] );
    if( logged == 'y' ){
        printf("Hello \n");
    } else {
        printf("Run hacker :(\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**And second code**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char logged = 'n';
    char pass[8];
    strcpy( pass, argv[1] );
    if( logged == 'y' ){
        printf("Hello \n");
    } else {
        printf("Run hacker :(\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These codes are vulnerable for stack overflow attack. (passing 'yyyyyyyyy' as arg would pass the test)

**But why?** Order of local variables in second code is different than in first code. So queue of pushing local variables on stack should be other too, but it is not?

Comment: The language standard doesn't say how variables are stored in memory, so the compiler can do whatever it feels work the best.

Comment: As noted as above - compiled with gcc 7 both programs produce exact same assembly. Additionally what is a purpose of producing code 'broken by design' ?

Answer (score 0):

First a stack overflow vulnerability is not exactly the same thing as stack corruption.

This code is writing an automatic variable that is allocated on the stack (in your frame). The compiler reserved 8 bytes on the stack for the pass string. If you write more than 8 bytes, you will be corrupting whatever else is on the stack right next to pass[] array. Doesn't really matter what it is; it will be corrupted, and that is what stack corruption means.

With some skill, one can generate an input (argv[1]) string (really an instruction byte stream) that will align with the return instruction from the main and thus can force execution of your code. That is what vulnerability is.

You seem to understand that the order of variables on your stack just determines what and how may be corrupted, and you should see exactly what you expected if you turn off the stack protection by using -fno-stack-protector, plus minus the exact stack layout imposed by your compiler. With the protection on, both cases should dump the stack smashing backtrace and diagnostics.

Note that different linux distrubution set the no-stack-protector default to different values, but as long as you explicitly control it on the command line you are all set. 
The -z execstack option is a mechanism dealing with whether or not to allow executing on the stack; here it is irrelevant as your code is just corrupting the stack.